# I made a mistake by trying to minimize the fan noise, typed "np" when prompted by fancontrol

Tags: fan, temperature, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I am new to Ubuntu Studio and as naive and without experience as I am, I made my first mistake.

I have an old iMac mid 2010 with a new SSD with a very noisy fan. So I downloaded
`lm-sensors` and then `fancontrol`.

That worked great. Then I made the mistake:

```
Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)np
Unloading cpuid... OK
```

By mistake I wrote `np`.

Now I am lost. I never used the terminal before, and I really like it, but I know too little.

The sensors are still shown when I run `sensors` and the command seems to work, but I have no real idea of what I did. And the fan is still like before.

Is it a big problem I caused? How should I react on `Unloading cpuid... OK`?

Comment: The default answer was the answer in capital letters. You responded "np" (neither yes nor no), which was taken as a default answer (same as if you'd just pressed enter), ie. you indirectly answered "no". You've installed them, but opted to not add those lines automatically to the `/etc/modules` file.

Answer (score 2):

`sensors-detect` is a helper utility that will update `/etc/modules` for you if you say `yes`. You can run it as many times as you want. Sometimes it duplicates entries, but it won't hurt anything.  Saying `no` (or `np`) will not update the file.

You can view the contents of `/etc/modules` to see what is there. The modules in that file are loaded at boot. If you did not save the entry and the file is empty, the modules it loaded before will not be loaded when you reboot.

You can manually load individual modules with the `modprobe` command at any point, or just run `sensors-detect` again to update the file.